# Spacing between elements (buttons, text boxes) on a page

Tags: visual-studio-2015, uwp, uwp-xaml

I have this on a page (https://i.stack.imgur.com/wPL8Y.png) and I wanted to leave a spacing between the various elements so they would not all be together as it is in the image. I want them to be more spread across the page and not all caught up to each other.
Code:

```
<TextBox x:Name="inputBox"
                 InputScope="Number"
                 RelativePanel.AlignVerticalCenterWithPanel="True"
                 Height="32" 
                 RelativePanel.AlignHorizontalCenterWithPanel="True"
                 TextWrapping="Wrap" 
                 PlaceholderText=""
                 Width="71"/>

        <Button x:Name="Calculate" Content="Calculate"
                RelativePanel.AlignHorizontalCenterWithPanel="True"
                RelativePanel.AlignVerticalCenterWithPanel="True"
                RelativePanel.Below="inputBox"
                Click="Calculate_Click"/>

        <TextBlock x:Name="ValorFinal"
                   RelativePanel.Below="Calculate"
                   RelativePanel.AlignVerticalCenterWithPanel="True"
                   RelativePanel.AlignHorizontalCenterWithPanel="True"
                   TextWrapping="Wrap"
                   Height="16" 
                   Text="Total:"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

add a margin if you need a gap

```
    <TextBox x:Name="inputBox"
             InputScope="Number"
             RelativePanel.AlignVerticalCenterWithPanel="True"
             Height="32" 
             RelativePanel.AlignHorizontalCenterWithPanel="True"
             TextWrapping="Wrap" 
             PlaceholderText=""
             Margin="0,10,0,0"
             Width="71"/>

    <Button x:Name="Calculate" Content="Calculate"
            RelativePanel.AlignHorizontalCenterWithPanel="True"
            RelativePanel.AlignVerticalCenterWithPanel="True"
            RelativePanel.Below="inputBox"
            Margin="0,10,0,0"
            Click="Calculate_Click"/>

    <TextBlock x:Name="ValorFinal"
               RelativePanel.Below="Calculate"
               RelativePanel.AlignVerticalCenterWithPanel="True"
               RelativePanel.AlignHorizontalCenterWithPanel="True"
               TextWrapping="Wrap"
               Height="16" 
               Margin="0,10,0,0"
               Text="Total:"/>
```